# Erasing a flash sector for STM32G474RE is not working

Tags: assembly, stm32, flash-memory, stm32cubeide

I am trying to design a UART bootloader for STM32G474RE microcontroller. I am having problem in Flash erasing part of the code. Before designing bootloader for STM32G474RE microcontroller, I tried for STM32F767Zi Nucleo kit. and it is working fine on that kit. The code for the Nucleo kit is as follows:

```
if( is_first_block )
{

  printf("Erasing the Flash memory...\r\n");
  //Erase the Flash
  FLASH_EraseInitTypeDef EraseInitStruct;
  uint32_t SectorError;

  EraseInitStruct.TypeErase     = FLASH_TYPEERASE_SECTORS;
  EraseInitStruct.Sector        = FLASH_SECTOR_5;
  EraseInitStruct.NbSectors     = 2;                    //erase 2 sectors(5,6)
  EraseInitStruct.VoltageRange  = FLASH_VOLTAGE_RANGE_3;

  ret = HAL_FLASHEx_Erase( &EraseInitStruct, &SectorError );
  if( ret != HAL_OK )
  {
    break;
  }
}
```

Here I am erasing 2 sectors.

Now when I am trying for STM32G474RE, I am having following issues:

1. There is no option to erase sectors (Only pages)
2. EraseInitStruct.VoltageRange  = FLASH_VOLTAGE_RANGE_3; this command is giving error when I compile the code. (I have checked stm32g4xx_hal_flash.h file but there is no information about it whereas stm32f7xx_hal_flash.h file has information about it.). I get the following two errors:
   - The macro `FLASH_VOLTAGE_RANGE_3` is not #defined
   - The structure `FLASH_EraseInitTypeDef` has no member named `VoltageRange`

It would be great if some could help me and guide me about these issue from their experience.

Comment: See example `FLASH_EraseProgram`, that comes with the library. STM32G4 uses a different flash controller than STM32F7, the code can't be just copied.

Comment: Flex, can you please attach a link for the example?

Comment: You can find it [here](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeG4/tree/master/Projects/STM32G474E-EVAL/Examples/FLASH/FLASH_EraseProgram), but it is also included under Repository folder in your Cube installation. To find the local repository location see Help->Updater Settings of the Stm32CubeMX start page.

Comment: I modified your question: I removed the screen shot and described the error messages using text. On this web site, screen shots of text should not be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is no option to erase sectors (Only pages)

Did you mean: "No option to erase **pages** (only **sectors**)"?

Or did you mean: "No option to erase a complete **bank**"?

`HAL_FLASHEx_Erase` erases one or more sectors, not pages. A sector consists of multiple pages.

And a sector is the smallest unit that can be erased due to hardware restrictions.

You cannot erase less than a whole sector because the hardware does not support erasing parts of a sector.

> `EraseInitStruct.VoltageRange = FLASH_VOLTAGE_RANGE_3;`

I just looked into the header files of STM32**F**4xx and STM32**L**4xx:

STM32**F**4xx has a field named `VoltageRange` in the structure `FLASH_EraseInitTypeDef`, STM32**L**4xx does not have such a field.

And of course the macro `FLASH_VOLTAGE_RANGE_3` is also not defined for the STM32**L**4xx because the corresponding field is missing.

You are using an STM32**G**4xx. If that CPU does not take the `VoltageRange` information, you must simply remove the complete line (`EraseInitStruct.VoltageRange = FLASH_VOLTAGE_RANGE_3`) from your code.

Comment: Thank you very much Martin. STM32G474RE have options to erase pages and banks only, not an individual sector.

now I will count the number of pages in a sector and will erase it. Is that the right approach?